# How to write xpath for JavaScript link in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="tablesstyle01">
<table.  >
<thead class="options">...<thead>
<t body>
<tr class="zervta01">
<td>23455</TD>
<td> gg</TD>
<td>2345gg5</TD>
<TD>
<a href="JavaScript:revoke('2567')" title="Revo" class="revo"></a> == $0
</TD>
```

I want to click the href link. It is is table. Many TD are there last one I need to click.
X path is `//*[@id="#"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[8]/a`

Script is not clicking.

I wrote x path `//td[contains(class(),'revo')]` it doesn't work.

Pls help

Comment: did you used xpath with title? what is the exception?

Comment: Same as unable to find the element or invalid locator type

Comment: is it inside any frame?

Comment: try `//td/a[contains(@class,'revo')]`